# Replace a value in a column in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a data like this:

```
     x                       y         Dec
0,526315789473684   4,32808638960238    1
0,407407407407407   5,61296415952669    1
0,285714285714286   4,80940239482732    2
0,129032258064516   7,31517603835356    1
0,370370370370370   6,82876196429676    2
.........................................
```

I would like it to be :

```
   x                       y            Dec
0,526315789473684   4,32808638960238    yes
0,407407407407407   5,61296415952669    yes
0,285714285714286   4,80940239482732    no
0,129032258064516   7,31517603835356    yes
0,370370370370370   6,82876196429676    no
.........................................
```

I would like to change the "1" as "yes" and "2" as "no" in the "Dec" column. 
How can I do this?

Comment: What is data type of column `Dec`

Comment: Dec's data type is Factor

Comment: Coerce `Dec` variable to factor and change level names. You can do the last step by hand or use a "mapping" function, like `mapvalues` from package `plyr`.

Comment: why is this too complicated. isn't there a find and replace kind of thing

Comment: I am trying mapvalues now.. I did this.. my data frame name is "mydataR1" mapvalues(mydataR1, 1, YES) it said, object "YES" not found

Comment: I also did mapvalues(mydataR1$dec, 1, YES) it says "object YES" not found

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
levels(df$Dec) <- c(2,1)
```

Replace "df" with your dataframe name

Comment: it does not work . gives "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" error

Comment: Could you share the output of **levels(df$Dec)**, replace "df" with your actual data.frame name

Comment: it says error in *tmp* $Dec : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Are you sure it is factor. Just check with **class(tmp$Dec)**

Comment: sorry, levels(df$Dec) command gives "1", "2" result  I changed the value for df, my bad

Comment: I think you have already tried the levels command that I gave, so it is saying 1 and 2. Now check the tmp dataframe . Share any reproducible code for us to try